Why does all my plots in R have a outline/ border?
I am trying to make plots for my data. I am currently using the webr package plot nested pie charts.  All the plots that i have made has a (outline/ border) like in this picture:
Can someone help me remove this (outline/border) and resolve the issue?
Please find the code below
library(tidyverse)
library(webr)

g<- data.frame(
  animal=c( "Alpaca", "Donkey", "Dog ", "Cat"),
  A=c(50,215,15,21),
  B=c(22,55,1,5),
  C=c(58,1,5,15))

l_g<-g %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-"animal",names_to = "Condition", values_to = "value")

P_ge<-l_g%>% group_by(Condition, animal) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(value), .groups="drop")

PieDonut(P_ge, aes(Condition, animal, count=n),
         labelposition=1, 
         r0=0.5, 
         r1=0.95, 
       explode = 2, explodeDonut = TRUE)


I ran your code and get the same plot, but no outline. How are you viewing the plot? Are you saving it to a file?

@Axeman RStudio creates the border

@stefan_aus_hannover Not for me...

@Axeman I view my plots in R studio, I have tried exporting my plots in different formats but the border is still there. I can crop off the border in another application but it also masks some of the legends in the plot

This solution is a bit hacky, but I couldn't see any other way. I think there is something weird going on with the PieDonut function.
Use theme_void() to omit the axes and then run your modified code twice, saving the plots to an R object. Then use grid.newpage() from the grid package to put them together.
p1 <- PieDonut(P_ge, aes(pies=Condition, count=n),
               labelposition=2, 
               r0=0.5, 
               r1=0.95) +
  theme_void()

p2 <- PieDonut(P_ge, aes(pies=Condition, donuts=animal, count=n),
               labelposition=1, 
               r0=0.5, 
               r1=0.95) +
  theme_void()

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
print(p1, vp = viewport(height = 1, width = 1))
print(p2, vp = viewport(height = 1, width = 1))




I added the above codes too, which removed the border but also removed my inner pie donut chart , it gave me a similar plot like the one i got for function theme_void.

Yes - I don't know why it removes the inner donut. But combining the two plots seems to work (for me anyway).

View image: https://livekentac-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/gt301_kent_ac_uk/EYxzxFYE_tpGitvJn0iIT30Bs5_WU6pY5Rx2F3TUrW8IqQ?e=DVAJup

Did you add p2? print(p2, vp = viewport(height = 1, width = 1)). You need to run my code exactly as I typed it. Don't modify it. I see you still have exploded=TRUE.

Thank you very much. I copied the codes exactly, and it worked. Can I still explode condition B as it the the condition of interest for my  research? Thanks

Yes, I think so.
